# OpenSSL command line secp384r1 / SHA-256 digital signatures

Tags: openssl, elliptic-curve

Is it possible to generate digital signatures using secp384r1 / SHA-256 from the OpenSSL command line (I'm using version 1.0.1c)? After some experimentation I can generate signatures with SHA-1 using:

```
openssl dgst -sign ec-key.pem -ecdsa-with-SHA1 -binary < test.bin > sig.bin
```

but

```
openssl dgst -sign ec-key.pem -ecdsa-with-SHA256 -binary < test.bin > sig.bin
```

just gives me a known option for '-ecdsa-with-SHA256'?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try use `-sha256` instead of `-ecdsa-with-SHA256`, and use an EC key to sign it.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I get this error: `Error Signing Data
56895:error:0606B06E:digital envelope routines:EVP_SignFinal:wrong public key type:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-52.30.1/src/crypto/evp/p_sign.c:99:`. Based on the error message, I suspect `-sha256` implies RSA.